# java のラッパクラス(Integer等)について質問です

Tags: java

環境：android studio 4.x
api：28

JAVA には、プリミティブ型の int のラッパークラス Integer（参照型） がありますが、このラッパークラスを使用すると、オートボクシング機能？で、以下のコードを記載してもプリミティブ型／参照型への双方向変換が自動で行われ、ビルドエラーは発生しません。（認識違いがあるかもしれませんが。。。）

```java
Integer v0 = 1;
int v1 = new Integer(1);
```

そこで、質問なのですが、以下のように Number クラスを継承した Int32 ラッパークラスを作成してみたのですが、オートボクシング機能が働かないようなのです。そもそも自作クラスにオートボクシング機能を利用することはできないのでしょうか？もしくは使い方が間違っているのでしょうか？（Nummberクラスを継承すれば何かしらオートボクシングが勝手に働くことを期待していました。。。）

```java
class Int32 extends Number {
    int value;
    public Int32(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return (int)value;
    }
    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return (long)value;
    }
    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return (float)value;
    }
    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return (double)value;
    }
}
Int32 i32 = 0; // <--- ここでエラーが発生する
```

JAVA初心者のため認識違いがあるかもしれませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ボクシング対象はJavaの言語仕様で限定されていて自分で追加できません。
[JLS15 5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) に書かれています。

> Boxing conversion treats expressions of a primitive type as expressions of a corresponding reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> - From type boolean to type Boolean
> - From type byte to type Byte
> - From type short to type Short
> - From type char to type Character
> - From type int to type Integer
> - From type long to type Long
> - From type float to type Float
> - From type double to type Double
> - From the null type to the null type